Permutations in two rows
There are 8 cars to be parked in 8 parking slots.
But there are two rows containing four slots each.
How many different ways are there to park 8 cars in two rows?
My Attempt - ${8}\choose{4}$ $\times 4!$ $\times$${4}\choose{4}$$\times 4!$ = 8!
It is the same as arranging them in a line.
Is there something that I am missing ?

The question is not clear. Maybe we are interested only by the 2 rows ? How many ways to choose the 4 cars that are in each row ?

To better understand why they are the same

your method chooses $4$ cars for, say, the top row, permutes them. The cars for the bottom row automatically get chosen $\left[\binom44 =1\right]$ so permute them in the bottom row

$8!$ permutes all the cars in a row, and then divides them at the middle with the first half for the top row  and the second half for the bottom row


